# Inserting line breaks in message of php mail function (userdetails)

Tags: php, email

This is the code that I am using to send mail. But to have line breaks in message that is to be delivered in mail is not inserting new lines. I tried using "
","/n","/r/n". But i am getting these along with the message or else message is not at all getting delivered.

```
     <?php
      $to="******";
      $sub="contact_details";

    $userdetails="Name:".$_REQUEST["name"];
    $userdetails.="<br/>Phone number:".$_REQUEST["phone"];
    $userdetails.="<br/>Email:".$_REQUEST["email"]";
    $userdetails.="<br/>Message:".$_REQUEST["message"].`"<br>"`;

    if($_REQUEST["name"] && $_REQUEST["phone"] && $_REQUEST["email"] && $_REQUEST["message"])
    {
        $mail=mail($to,$sub,$userdetails);
        if($mail){

            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Submitted Successfully!')
                 </script>";
        }

        else{
            echo"<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Failed!')</script>";
        }
    }
    else {

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Please enter all fields!');
                 </script>";    
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to send HTML mail. For that set header for html type. Refer PHP mail function for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The email that you are sending is not html supported, yow will need to add `\n` and in order to make the html work, you will need to add headers like this:

```
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Some how it worked like a charm. I did not add any headers. But just used "\r\n" . Now everything is working as required. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct the syntax for errors, you have added extra "(double quote) after email, remove this, and you can use "\n" for adding the line breaks.

```
   <?php
    $to="******";
    $sub="contact_details";

    $userdetails="Name:".$_REQUEST["name"]. "\n";
    $userdetails.="<br/>Phone number:".$_REQUEST["phone"]. "\n";
    $userdetails.="<br/>Email:".$_REQUEST["email"]. "\n";
    $userdetails.="<br/>Message:".$_REQUEST["message"]. "\n";

?>
```

Also header are not mandatory to send the mail, you can send the mail even if header are not set.